# Site Navbar interact with Tableau iFrame

Tags: python, css, tableau-api, jss

I have embedded a Tableau dashboard/worksheet into a website via iframe. I'm looking to build navigation from the parent site that directly interacts with the embedded dashboard so users can click between views (vs. adding the tabs to Tableau). Coming up short. Any idea how this is possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can continue using the JavaScript API with this function

```
 function switchTab() {
   workbook.activateSheetAsync("<YOUR SHEET NAME>");
 }
```

And then just call the function with the onclick event from your buttons.
Full tutorial is here. [js api tutorial](https://help.tableau.com/samples/en-us/js_api/tutorial.htm)